# How to connect into Action Cable websocket from Arduino?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, arduino, actioncable, arduino-esp8266

I built an app in Python Flask which controls the LED light on an Arduino through broadcasting the color selected in a form to all members of the websocket channel. I am now rebuilding in Rails and trying to determine how my Arduino can specify which channel it would like to join. I've already begun a connection to the WebSocket and seem to be getting the following back from Rails: `[WSc] Received text: {"type":"ping","message":1544679171}`.

Now I just need to determine how I can send in a request to specifically stream from the ArduinoChannel, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I've tried adding parameters to my `webSocket.begin`, but that doesn't seem to have any affect.

Below is my Arduino code for reference:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WebSocketsClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

// Initialize pins
int redpin = D0;
int greenpin = D2;
int bluepin = D4;

//// Connecting to the internet
const char* ssid = "**************";
const char* password = "******";

// Setting up the websocket client
WebSocketsClient webSocket;

// Set up the WiFi client;
WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);

  pinMode(redpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluepin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenpin, OUTPUT);


  delay(10);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while(WiFi.status()!= WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);  
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP() + "\n");
  Serial.print(WiFi.macAddress() + "\n");

  // Initializing the WS2812B communication
  setRgb(255,80,90);

  // Initializing the websocket connection

  webSocket.begin("192.168.1.93",3000, "/cable" );
//  webSocket.sendTXT('{"command":"subscribe","identifier":"{\"channel\":\"ArduinoChannel\"}"', 0);
  webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
  webSocket.setReconnectInterval(5);

}
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  webSocket.loop();

} 

void webSocketEvent(WStype_t type, uint8_t *payload, size_t length) {
  switch(type) {
    Serial.write(type);
    case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
      Serial.printf("[WSc] Disconnected!\n");
      break;
    case WStype_CONNECTED:
      Serial.printf("[WSc] Connected to url: %s\n", payload);
      break;
    case WStype_TEXT:
      Serial.printf("[WSc] Received text: %s\n", payload);
      DynamicJsonBuffer jBuffer;
      JsonObject &root = jBuffer.parseObject(payload);
      setRgb(root["r"],root["g"],root["b"]);
      break;
  }
}

  void setRgb(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b) {
  analogWrite(redpin, r);
  analogWrite(bluepin, b);
  analogWrite(greenpin, g);
  delay(10);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR:

> how I can send in a request to specifically stream from the ArduinoChannel

To receive streams from `ArduinoChannel`, you'll need to "subscribe" by sending through Websocket connection the following the String data from Arduino-client:

```
"{\"command\":\"subscribe\",\"identifier\":\"{\\\"channel\\\":\\\"ArduinoChannel\\\"}\"}"
```

... which is almost the same as your commented out `sendTXT` code, but that probably you were just incorrectly "escaping" the  double quotes.

### References:

I traced from the JS-client version of [`ActionCable` here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/app/assets/javascripts/action_cable.js)

1. ```
   App.cable.subscriptions.create('ArduinoChannel')
   ```
2. ```
   Subscriptions.prototype.create = function create(channelName, mixin) {
     var channel = channelName;
     var params = (typeof channel === "undefined" ? "undefined" : _typeof(channel)) === "object" ? channel : {
       channel: channel
     };
     // params = { channel: "ArduinoChannel" }
     var subscription = new Subscription(this.consumer, params, mixin);
     return this.add(subscription);
   };
   ```
3. ```
   function Subscription(consumer) {
     var params = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : {};
     var mixin = arguments[2];
     classCallCheck(this, Subscription);
     this.consumer = consumer;
     this.identifier = JSON.stringify(params);
     extend(this, mixin);
   }
   ```
4. ```
   Subscriptions.prototype.add = function add(subscription) {
     this.subscriptions.push(subscription);
     this.consumer.ensureActiveConnection();
     this.notify(subscription, "initialized");
     this.sendCommand(subscription, "subscribe");
     return subscription;
   };
   ```
5. ```
   Subscriptions.prototype.sendCommand = function sendCommand(subscription, command) {
     var identifier = subscription.identifier;
     // command =  "subscribe"; identifier = JSON.stringify(params) = '{"channel":"ArduinoChannel"}';
     return this.consumer.send({
       command: command,
       identifier: identifier
     });
   };
   ```
6. ```
   Consumer.prototype.send = function send(data) {
     // data = { command: 'subscribe', identifier: '{"channel":"ArduinoChannel"}' }
     return this.connection.send(data);
   };
   ```
7. ```
   Connection.prototype.send = function send(data) {
     if (this.isOpen()) {
       // JSON.stringify(data) = '{"command":"subscribe","identifier":"{\"channel\":\"ArduinoChannel\"}"}'
       this.webSocket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
       return true;
     } else {
       return false;
     }
   };
   ```

Comment: It was the quote escapes that were it. I also moved my sendTXT function down to the case statement to ensure it didn't send the text before the web socket connection was completed and it worked like a charm

Comment: @emijune Great to hear that! :)